# Context-free Language, Pumping lemma

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I want to prove that $ L = {a^n b^m c^{ \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor } }  $

isn't context free language, so I choose N - constant from lemma

so the word is
$ w = a^N b^N c $  and $ w = uvxyz $

1 case

v and y contains only a
$ v,y \in a^{*} $

and $ w_2 = a^{N+B} b^{N} c $ where $ B > 0 $
is it correct to say that it doesn't belong to language, because $ N + B \neq N $ ?

edit

or second version

$ v,y \in a^{*} $
so $w_0 = uv^0xy^0z = uxz $ and $ w_0 = a^{N-B}b^Nc $ which doesn't belong to language because $  \lfloor \frac{N-B}{N} \rfloor = 0 \neq 1 $

and what with case where $ v \in a^+ $ and $ y \in b^+ $

Comment: I trust you realize that you left off quite a few other cases. For instance, it might be the case that $vxy = a^tb^s$. Also, in the case you noted, it might be the case that $\lfloor (N+B)/N\rfloor$ might still be 1 (though that can be fixed by more pumping).

Comment: Yes, I know that there are more cases, but I was not sure if this one is correct, but if this one is incorrect, how to prove that ? I added second version

Comment: Strings of that form *are* a context free language, so you won't be able to get a contradiction.

Comment: maybe on $ w = a^{N}b^{N}c $ pumping lemma not work , but language L isn't context free. I proved it to word $ w = a^{N^2} b^N c^N $